# Dynamic XFA PDF issue with chrome ("Please wait...")

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, pdf.js, xfa, pdfium

I am having issue to view XFA PDF in Google chrome. I am able to open the same PDF in Acrobat reader but when I view in chrome I get “Please wait...”  message.

Can you please let me know if there is any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Please refer to [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. Otherwiese we can't help you!

Answer (score 4):

The XML Forms Architecture is deprecated in ISO 32000-2 (released in 2017). One of the reasons for deprecation was the fact that adoption of XFA was poor. This wasn't a problem when Adobe Reader had a high penetration, but it became problematic with the advent of pdf.js, Chrome's PDF viewer, Microsoft's PDF viewer, etc. None of those viewers supported XFA. Instead of rendering the XML stream, they just render the single (static) PDF page that is usually stored inside an XFA document. PDF renders much quicker than XML, and the static PDF page saying "Please wait..." was there to bridge the gap between opening the document and rendering the XML in Adobe Reader. It's also the page that is shown by PDF viewers who don't support XFA. Those viewers know how to render the PDF part of the form, but they don't know how to parse the XFA stream.

> To make a long story short: there is no fix for your issue. Google Chrome doesn't support XFA, and as XFA is deprecated, Google Chrome won't support XFA in the future either.

There might be a workaround if you are allowed to flatten the form. For instance: XFA is often used as a templating format.

- The template defines what a final document has to look like.
- XML data is merged into the template.
- The XFA template with the data is flattened to an ordinary PDF document.

Once an XFA form is flattened to an ordinary PDF document, the document is no longer interactive. No data can be entered; all interactivity is gone. There is no XFA XML stream inside the document anymore.

There are two products that can flatten an XFA form: Adobe LC Enterprise Suite, and iText's pdfXFA add-on. Both of these products are closed source, commercial products.